# Magento 2 - How to find out which data is available for an object?

Tags: magento2, model, quote, class, object

I have a quote item:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
 */
protected $_cartFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\CartFactory $cartFactory,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_cartFactory = $cartFactory;
    ...
}

...   
/** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart */
$cart = $this->_cartFactory->create();

/** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
$quote = $cart->getQuote();
```

How can I figure out, which attributes are available/accessible for $quote?
I know for example that I can call `$quote->getTotals()` because I found it somewhere in another code.

How do I know all attributes which I can access?

I tried:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/shipping.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);

$data= $quote->getData();
$logger->info("Data: ");
$logger->info($data);
```

But it does not print anything and my site stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way. It only works by using [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) or extensions like [ChromePhp](https://github.com/ccampbell/chromephp).